# paper.js point math not working

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Even though the `paper.js` documentation states that it is possible to do [implicit additions](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#add) on points or [assignements with [x,y]](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/) (first block of code, line 17), I can not get this to work. Any point resulting from math of the type `point3 = point2 - point1` has undefined `x` and `y` properties, whereas they are well defined in the points after creation with `new`.

I have created [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F2jx/5/) to reproduce the errors I am getting.

What have I missed in my code, please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [page you link to](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/) says:

> PaperScript code is loaded just like any other JavaScript using the `<script>` tag, except for the type being set to `"text/paperscript"` or `"text/x-paperscript"`. The code can either be an external file (`src="URL"`), or inlined:

Once you put your code in a `<script type="text/paperscript">` tag, it works:

[jsfiddle.net/2F2jx/6](http://jsfiddle.net/2F2jx/6/)

**Edit:** To use a linked script, it's no different. You set the `type` attribute:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and the fiddle update. I omitted to mention that I need to have the Paperscript in a separate Javascript file, since all this will be integrated into Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @frogFangio - It doesn't matter if the script is inline or linked. Either way you set the `type` attribute on the script tag.

Comment: OK I see your point. I am going to implement it as you proposed. Thanks again for your support !!

Answer (score 0):

The PaperJS on your link is v0.22 and the latest version is v0.9.12, so if you are using the online reference http://paperjs.org/reference/ your code work with the version 0.22.